# Setters in template classes

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to find a good way to write a setter function for a template class. For non-template classes if somehow trivial because the function signature/implementation depends on parameter type. For example if the parameter type is `int` the next function should be optimal:

```
void MyClass::Set(int value)
{
    myValue = value;
}
```

If the parameter type is `std::vector` next implementation should be close to optimal:

```
void MyClass::Set(std::vector<SomeType> value)
{
    std::swap(myValue, value);
}
```

as the right constructor (move or copy) will be used to construct the function parameter and no unnecessary copying occurs, assuming move constructor cost is negligible.

As you can see both implementations have drawbacks when the type is changed: If the type is changed to `std::vector` for the first version, at least one unnecessary copy is made increasing the actual cost by a factor of 2 or 3.
If the type changed to `int` in the second version 2 unnecessary copies are made, increasing the actual cost by a factor of 3.

**Can you please give me a good generic implementation for a setter function (maybe with overloads)? It should be optimal/close to optimal for any type used as parameter.**

PS: I would prefer to not use `std::enable_if` to make several type dependent setters as the class will increase dramatically.

Comment: Are you familiar with r value references and/or universal references?

Comment: If you have no idea what data type you are setting, why even use a setter? It's not like you can maintain any class invariant that way; sounds like a justifiable use case of a `struct`, not a `class`, just leave the member public, and let the user assign to it optimally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a forwarding reference to accept either an *rvalue* or an *lvalue*, then forward that to the appropriate move or copy assignment operator:

```
template <typename T>
void Set(T && value) {
    myValue = std::forward<T>(value);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me how is T deduced in the next 2 cases: Set(1) and Set(std::complex<double>{1.0, 2.0});

Comment: @Felics: `int&&` and `complex&&`

Comment: Thank you! And another question if you are kind to answer me - is it optimal for ints to be passed as int&& s?

Comment: @Felics: Theoretically, no - the extra indirection could have a cost. Practically, yes - the function call will be inlined and optimised in the context of the caller, removing the indirection.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I've been preferring the term "universal references" for a while, and more and more I see "forwarding reference" preferred instead. What's your take on the semantics?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks! I was afraid of the extra indirection, that's why I asked those additional questions.

Comment: @AndyG: "Universal" is an old name for the idea, but it turned out not to be "universal" in any meaningful way, so I don't use that name. "Forwarding" is more accurate and descriptive. There's no standard name; the standard just describes the reference collapsing rules that give rise to the forwarding behaviour.

Comment: Corrections: look, for the next 2 cases: `Set(1)` and `Set(std::complex<double>{1.0, 2.0})` -- `T` is deduced to be `int` and `complex`, it's function argument (T&&) to be deduced as `int&&` and `complex&&`

Answer (score 0):

You should have 3 overloads.

```
void Set( T&& t ) {
  v = std::move(t);
}
void Set( T const& t ) {
  v = t;
}
template<class U>
void Set( U&& u ) {
  v = std::forward<U>(u);
}
```

the first two allow implicit conversion to work well, if the caller uses `{}` initialization on the argument, or if the caller is the name of a function and it needs a context, or a few other cases: it will work.  This fixes some of the bigger annoyances with "perfect forwarding".

The third gives you anything for which your `operator=` is overloaded to handle that isn't covered by the first two.  It is an example of "perfect forwarding", which as the name implies is imperfect.

The most common problem if you only use the 3rd overload, `.Set( {construction args} )` doesn't work.

Possibly the `const&` overload is redundant, but I am unsure.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f6c2dcdafddb79b)

---

```
// and sometimes:
template<class...Us>
void Set( Us&&...us ) {
  v = {std::forward<Us>(us)...};
}
```

The forth is an emplace-set.  This is not actually useful in this case (where we are using `operator=`), but in some cases it can be.  For an example of where such an emplace-accessor is useful, `optional::value_or` should have that overload.  Basically, cases where you could directly construct the target value, or where other parameters might lead to you *not* constructing the value, this is useful: if you do a `{std::forward<Us>(us)...}` always you might as well use `.Set( {args...} )` externally, which calls the first overload above.